# Mapping classes to multiple databases

Tags: .net, nhibernate, mapping

How do I make `NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport` to export certain classes in one database, and certain in another one?  E.g. `Person` class should be mapped to a database with one connection string, and `Product` should be saved to a different database, so `SchemaExport` should create a `Person` table in one DB, and a `Product` table in the second one.

I defined NHibernate mappings for my classes, but I don't know where to specify the database/connection string for each class separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mappings are Database independent, there is no way to define a connectionstring in them. Build up two configuration objects, one for each database and add all classes to appropriate configuration. Then use Schemaexport for each config.

```
var config1 = new Configuration()
    .AddClass(typeof(Person))
    .AddClass(typeof(Customer))
...

new SchemaExport(config1).Create(false, true);

var config2 = new Configuration()
    .AddClass(typeof(Product));

new SchemaExport(config2).Create(false, true);
```

Comment: *all classes to appropriate configuration* - that's the part I am not sure how to do.

Comment: Many thanks! The `AddClass` method seems to be what I was looking for. I was using `AddAssembly` simply by inertia, from all the web examples, didn't even think I could have finer granulation using `AddClass`.